# Возврат на предыдущую страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Задача стоит следующая

Сайт построен на Wordpress 5.2.2

Есть 3 родительских блока каждый с разным `id` которые добавлены в меню, в самих блоках есть ещё дополнительные элементы-категории, при нажатии на элемент-категории посетитель переходит к категории сайта.

Когда пользователь нажимает в `браузере` кнопку назад должен вернутся в исходное положение к выбору элементов-категории, но так чтоб сам блок был по середине экрана.

[image: images_2]

При переходе с меню(ссылка сделана якорь на родительский блок'#blok1') родительский блок становится точно по центру страницы.

[image: images_1]

Пробовал решить данную проблему через `localStorage` где записываю `id` блока с которого переходит пользователь

```
 $(".wrapper_body .categ_block").on("click", function(){
    var locItem = $(this).attr('id');
     var linkST = window.location.href;
     localStorage.setItem('linkSite', linkST);
     localStorage.setItem('backUpHist', locItem);
});
```

и на странице уже самой категории при возврате назад пробую подменить ссылку на свою

```
var locItems = localStorage.getItem('backUpHist');
var siteLink =  localStorage.getItem('linkSite');
var linksBl = siteLink+"#"+locItems; 
 console.log(linksBl);
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    window.location.href =  linksBl;
};
```

Но когда пользователь прокрутит родительский блок вверх или вниз, то пользователь возвращается на ту позицию с которой он переходил в категории, как на второй картинке.

Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение нашлось долгими часами тестов, спасибо всем за помощь в решении задачи.

```js
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
var locItems = localStorage.getItem('backUpHist');
var siteLink =  localStorage.getItem('linkSite');
var linksBl = siteLink + "/#"+locItems; 
 
window.history.pushState({page: 1}, "", "");
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  if(event){
    window.location.href = linksBl;
  }
};

});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в том, что Chrome сам по себе запоминает позицию скролла, и при возвращение назад отдает предпочтение ей, а не элементу из якоря.

Эту фичу можно отключить, однако в моих тестах тогда браузер переставал и переходить к элементу из урла. Но можно перейти к нему самому:

```
  // отключаем автовосстановление скролла
  if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
    history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'
  }
  // переходим к элементу
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    const hash = window.location.hash
    location.hash = ""
    location.hash = hash
  })
```

Второй вариант без отключения этой фичи - прокручивать к элементу из хеша самим с помощью js

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   if (window.location.hash) {
     setTimeout(function() { document.querySelector(window.location.hash).scrollIntoView() }, 0)
   }
 })
```

setTimeout(..., 0) добавляет задачу в конец текущей очереди, чтобы прокрутка выполнилась после восстановления скролла браузером.
В этом способе будет небольшой лаг при открытии страницы, т.к. к элементу переходит после загрузки всей страницы.

Третий вариант - обмануть восстановление скролла браузера, перед закрытием страницы установив в нужное нам положение

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
   if (window.location.hash) {
     document.querySelector(window.location.hash).scrollIntoView()
   }
 })
```

Тут будет небольшой лаг перед переходом(перед закрытием страницы), но открываться она будет лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо `window.location.href` нужно использовать [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Comment: поменял `window.location.href` на `history.pushState()` но ситуация не извенилась -

 `$(document).ready(function(){
var locItems = localStorage.getItem('backUpHist');
var siteLink =  localStorage.getItem('linkSite');
var linksBl = "/#"+locItems; 
console.log(linksBl);
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){
history.pushState({}, "",  linksBl);
  };
});`

Comment: Ситуация:  **извиняюсь**.

Comment: `изменилась` ;) у меня клавиатура без кирилицы по этому иногда есть ошибки)